# MVC Error - The model item passed into the dictionary is of type

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm getting this error in `_GalleryImages.cshtml`, and I'm passing the right Model.

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
> 'PageContent.Models.Gallery', but this dictionary requires a model
> item of type 'Base.Models.Pagination'.

**Gallery.cshtml**

```
@using PageContent.Models
@model Gallery

<section>
 .
 .
 .
 @Html.Partial("~/Views/_GalleryImages.cshtml", Model)
</section>
```

**_GalleryImages.cshtml**

```
@using PageContent.Models
@using Base.Models
@model Gallery
@{
  Pagination pagination = Model != null ? Model.Pagination : null;
}
<section>
 .
 .
 .
 @Html.Partial("~/Views/_Pagination.cshtml", pagination)
</section>
```

**_Pagination.cshtml**

```
@using Base.Models
@model Pagination

<section>
 .
 .
 .    
</section>
```

**Gallery.cs**

```
namespace PageContent.Models
{
    using Base.Models;
    public class Gallery
    {
        public Pagination Pagination {get; set;}
    }
}
```

**Pagination.cs**

```
namespace Base.Models
{
    public class Pagination
    {
    }
}
```

I tried passing `Model.Pagination` like this

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/_Pagination.cshtml", Model.Pagination)
```

But it did not work. So, assigned this to a variable inside the view and no luck with that too.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: For clarification, that error just means that your view is expecting a ModelX but you are trying to instantiate it with a ModelY instead. So basically you just have to ensure that you are passing the correct Model to the correct View.

Modify your `_GalleryImages.html` as followed

```
@using PageContent.Models
@using Base.Models
@model Gallery

@{
  Pagination pagination = Model != null ? Model.Pagination : null;
}

<section>
 .
 .
 .
 @Html.Partial("~/Views/_Pagination.cshtml", pagination)
</section>
```

You can use `@{ ... }` to define your variables. If you want to use a model value you will have to write `Model.Value` instead of just passing the parameter; you will be obtaining the value from inside your Model.

On a side note, you should populate your model from your controller instead of assigning values inside the view. Then as mentioned before just pass the values using the `Model.` prefix. ie; `@Html.Partial("~/Views/_Pagination.cshtml", Model.Pagination)`.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I have the `@` in my view. Also, the values are assigned in the controller. But `Model.Pagination` wasn't working. So, I tried assigning it again to a new variable in the view.

Comment: If so then this looks to be correct. Perhaps clean solution and try again?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the `Model.Pagination`. It was being passed as null. The MVC error was misleading.